# sharepoint 2010 InfoPath Form creates tasks

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

So I have 1 Document library and 1 Tasks list.

In the workflow when a new info path form is saved depending on various questions tasks are created in the tasks list.

I have a webart displaying all the tasks grouped by the document title.

My question is:

when a the workflow is completed for the document approval how can I hide/close those related tasks?

I am trying to do a lookup from the document library to bring in the Date Closed field that will be my webpart filter.

I can not link the 2 records togeter to display the closed date for that document.

not sure if this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

When task is finshed then it updates the task status to  completed. Try to query only not comepleted task in your webpart.